# Pseudocode for show advertising()

Tags: class, object, pseudocode

Need help on how to write a pseudocode for a showadvertising() functionality. This function will display an advertisement while the user is waiting for the 5 day weather forecast to show.

Comment: This question to me seems about as vague as it can get

Comment: Yeah thats what my prof gave me and even I thought it was vague so don't know how to start it but here is the scenario:

Comment: Scenario: You are tasked to design a Weather App.  The following characteristics apply:
 • The initial implementation is a basic Weather app, showing current temperature and condition (sunny, rain, snow, cloudy, etc), as well as a 5 day forecast.
 • Later Implementations will include hourly forecast, ability to add multiple locations, and weather maps.
 • The Application may be developed for various platforms.

Comment: I created a class model with the classes weather app, weather api, weather station, user, forecast, etc. Then added advertising agency, client, and advertisement. Based on this, the assignment wants us to write a pseudocode for the show advertising() functionality as the user waits for the forecast to display